# Detect specific character in URL string and replace it with another character

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have this URL string saved as NSString:

```
NSString *currentURL = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

https://www.tripresso.com/cooperation/toyota?utm_source=cooperation&utm_medium=toyota&utm_campaign=toyota_app?dxid=7019b21e-bd3b-4bde-8917-f353149bdda4&appid=com.hotai.toyota.citydriver.official
```

As you can see there are 2 `?` in this string. My question is how can I replace the second `?` with `&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all but the first occurrence, then this should work:

```
NSString *currentURL = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
NSMutableArray *components = [[currentURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"] mutableCopy];
NSString *firstComponent = [components firstObject];
[components removeObject:firstComponent];
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", firstComponent, [components componentsJoinedByString:@"&"]];
```